# What is the difference between「働かせる」and 「使う」?

Tags: nuances, verbs

What is the difference between the two sentences?

「その特のなぞを解くに、自分の頭を働かせた。」

「その特のなぞを解くに、自分の頭を使った。」

Comment: What's the difference in English between 'use your head' and 'exercise your brain power'? One's just a slightly more interesting way of saying the same thing.

Comment: `その特のなぞを解くに` -- You probably meant to say 「なぞを解く**の**に」... but what did you try to say by 「その[特]{とく}の」? Maybe you tried to type 「その[時]{とき}の」?

Comment: -1 for no research effort

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences have the same meaning, as in "using my brains".